# How to hide the ringer view in an app?

Tags: ios, mpvolumeview

I know how to hide the volume alert that pops up with the code below, but it doesn't work with the ringer. Is there a way to hide that too? I've searched everywhere and nothing is popping up

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(-500, -500, 0, 0);
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```